# how to retry connect ampq in Elixir

Tags: rabbitmq, elixir

I'm trying to connect to a RabbitMQ instance using the ampq package on Elixir, but at times the RabbitMQ instance won't be available at the time that the Elixir server is running. I was wondering how I might be able to implement a simple retry mechanism.  There's one strategy [here](https://tjheeta.github.io/2014/12/24/elixir-external-process-supervisor-restart-pattern/) but that seems more involved than I feel necessary especially since there's a mention of it on the README about more information being found on the official docs.  I unfortunately couldn't find anything.

Edit: This will crash the application on start and exit.

My code for the module is as follows:

#### Server.Gen.Rabbit (child)

```
defmodule Server.Gen.Rabbit do
  use GenServer
  use AMQP

  defmodule State do
    @type t :: %{
            id: String.t(),
            chan: map()
          }

    defstruct id: "", chan: nil
  end

  def start_link(%{id: id}) do
    GenServer.start_link(
      __MODULE__,
      %State{
        id: id
      },
      name: :"#{id}:rabbit"
    )
  end

  def init(opts) do
    host = "amqp://guest:guest@localhost"
    case Connection.open(host) do
      {:ok, conn} ->
        {:ok, chan} = Channel.open(conn)
        setup_queue(opts.id, chan)

        :ok = Basic.qos(chan, prefetch_count: 1)
        queue_to_consume = @online_receive_queue <> opts.id
        IO.puts("queue_to_consume_online: " <> queue_to_consume)
        {:ok, _consumer_tag} = Basic.consume(chan, queue_to_consume, nil, no_ack: true)

        {:ok, %State{chan: chan, id: opts.id}}
      {:error, _} ->
        IO.puts("[Rabbit] error on connecting to server: #{host}")
        {:backoff, 5_000}
      end
  end
```

#### Server (parent)

```
defmodule Server do
  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    import Supervisor.Spec, warn: false

    children = [
      {
        GenRegistry,
        worker_module: Server.Gen.Rabbit
      },
      Plug.Cowboy.child_spec(
        scheme: :http,
        plug: Server.Router,
        options: [
          port: String.to_integer(System.get_env("PORT") || "3000"),
          dispatch: dispatch(),
          protocol_options: [idle_timeout: :infinity]
        ]
      )
    ]

    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: Server.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end
end
```

Comment: just add the genserver to a supervisor, if the connection fails it will automatically restart the process.

Comment: thank you! I'm very new to Elixir and it sounds like what I'm looking to do should be fairly trivial. As of right now, the entire application exits, presumably due to it being linked?  There appears to be a supervisor at the parent level, which I'll add.

Comment: you can generate supervision tree using the --sup option when using mix new, if you generate a phoenix application the supervision tree gets generated automatically.